# Multiple IP connections

Tags: networking, router, ip

I have 3 routers which has separate Ethernet (wireless) connections with it's own IP.

On my Win7 I want to configure all three of them on my computer - I would like to have something like 3 local connections under my 'Network adapters' which are still completely independent. I assume this must go via some switch? Why I am doing this? Because I would like to have 3 web browsers opened in parallel (at the same time) and all of them to have different IPs (from above mentioned 'lines'). How to do all this?

Is this maybe possible by using multiple Ethernet ports? Thinking if somehow split my one port to 3 ports via some switch/router/hub I don't know and connect all 3 lines I would than have functional '3 LAN Connections'?

Comment: How than? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: Look, no I don't want to combine them at all, I don't want increased speed. I want for example to use forcebindIP application to bind one IP to one web browser, and bind another one to another web browser. I am achieving this with wireless connection of one router and Ethernet/cable connection of another router (two IPs in parallel).. But I have many routers so I need to have more 'network adapters' and I want to use them all for instance.. How?

Comment: Have I made my point with this?

Comment: Not at all... can you provide a diagram of what your trying to accomplish? It sounds like you want a separate network interface for each WiFi AP? For example, LAN 1 is connected to the internet via AP1's WiFi, LAN 2 is connected to the internet via AP2 WiFI, and LAN 3 is connected to the Internet via AP3's WiFi. and you want to have FireFox connect using LAN1, Chrome connect using LAN2, and Edge connect using LAN3... Is that what you are saying, because that is almost impossible.

Comment: It is almost like what you described.. I achieved to be on internet via two different IPs: LAN_1 vis ETH1, LAN_2 via AP2's WiFi and easily binding LAN_1 to one browser and LAN_2 another web browser I am on Internet with two different IPs. But instead of using AP's I think it would be better to use some "multi Ethernet port". Also one of possible solutions could also be Usb to Ethernet, but is there something like ETH device which do opposite of switch OR making multiple ETH ports from one port (my mother board have only 1 port)

Comment: Can you not just use VMs?

Comment: That would probably achieve the goal, but I want without VMs, there must be some other solution

Answer (score 1):

> I have 3 routers which has separate Ethernet (wireless) connections with it's own IP.

Ethernet isn't wireless - Ethernet is wired LAN.

> On my Win7 I want to configure all three of them on my computer

Then you need to connect all of them either into a single network using a switch or another router ...

> I would like to have something like 3 local connections under my 'Network adapters' which are still completely independent.

... or connect them separately using dedicated NICs.

> I assume this must go via some switch?

This would be be the single network approach. The routers would have to be configured to use the same network parameters (network address & mask) and different internal IP addresses.

> Because I would like to have 3 web browsers opened in parallel (at the same time) and all of them to have different IPs (from above mentioned 'lines').

You can easily open three web browsers and have them use a single connection. The point of a network is to provide virtually unlimited connectivity (many-to-many).

An application (browser) doesn't directly use an IP address. The application uses the operating system to handle all network connections. It doesn't care about how it is done. The operating system in turn uses the available network connections to fulfill the requests from any application currently running.

> Is this maybe possible by using multiple Ethernet ports?

This is also possible. Just add more NICs to your computer.

> Thinking if somehow split my one port to 3 ports via some switch/router/hub

A switch (or hub) doesn't split a port. It is a network concentrator you can connect many devices to so all devices can talk to each other.

Comment: Hi Zac67! Thank you for answer. Can you please tell me in final what shell I do than - what would you recommend me, considering fact that I can force specific application to go via certain network? How can I connect/all of them? Via concentrator or multiple NIC? Is there some device with multiple NIC?

Comment: The least hardware investment is configuring all routers to use the same internal network and connect them with a switch. You can then use the default gateway or specific routes to select which router to use.

Comment: Zac67 I am having 3 LAN cables from ADSL routers, so 3 completely random IPs, I put them into switch, right?